# react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer printPic error in iOS: blurred image

Tags: react-native, printing, escpos

Because the QR code printing failed, I switched to image printing, but I got this error
The image is clear at the top (about 5cm) and blurry at the bottom

[image: print image error here]

Can anyone help me.
Thanks

Comment: Even if you do not prepare the image yourself, the printer itself often has a QR code printing function. Are you using a printer that does not have a QR code printing function? Then your question has little specific information for someone to come up with advice or answers. Please add the information and program source/sample data.

Comment: thanks for reply me. I am following this library: [https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer](https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer), I use printer "nyear label np100" and use the app "Nyearlable" still print QR, but function BluetoothEscposPrinter.printPic() is not, every image

Comment: The description of the library you presented says it is for a TSC printer. Most of the control codes for these printers are based on ESC/POS, but they often extend their own functions for each vendor and model. Perhaps your printer did not support the QR code printing control commands that the library produces. You can get the control code material from the printer vendor, create the command data to print the QR code on the printer as a byte array, and send it.

Comment: thanks for replying me, i print on android normally but ios can't, so i don't understand why? I use the function to print the image, not the function to print the QR

Comment: Then add the result printed by Android so that others can compare it. Also, it may be easier to get advice and answers if you add the program source and sample data used for printing them.

Comment: @Tuấn Nguyễn I am facing an issue with my  Epson m30ii printer. It's a blue tooth printer. I am trying to implement a package for IOS I have already done the IOS configuration.  Can yu help me?